# What languages does the character encoding UTF-8 support?

Tags: character

What languages does UTF-8 support?

And how many languages does the UTF-8 support?

Comment: [List of Unicode characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_Characters)

Comment: Do you mean what programming languages support UTF-8 or what written languages can be expressed with UTF-8 characters?

Comment: As @DOK pointed out ,be clear with your question. clearly mention if you are looking for Programming languages or Language scripts ...

Comment: another important question closed by the oligarchs

Answer (score 8):

See the page [Supported Scripts](http://www.unicode.org/standard/supported.html) on unicode.org. UTF-8 supports all Unicode characters.

Note that Unicode defines character encodings, not languages.

> The Unicode Standard encodes scripts rather than languages per se. ...

Comment: In that page I don't see "Simplified Chinese" and "Traditional Chinese" but I know they are supported.  Are they listed with different names?

Comment: I think they're both grouped in the "Han" script - but I'm not very familiar with this (apparently relatively complex) issue with the Chinese scripts. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_unification which appears to have a lot of info.

Answer (score 3):

UTF-8 is suppose to represent any Unicode character.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8